# change text gravity to top in Android

Tags: android, textview, gravity, layout-gravity

I need to dynamically change Android text `Gravity` to the `TOP` in My ListItems.
Code used for ListItem:

**XML layout file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/ma_list_item_height">
                   ..............
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/driver_passage_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ma_list_item_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Ivanov Ivan Ivanich"
        android:padding="0"
        />
```

I have read about `Gravity` and property `setIncludeFontPadding`, I have tried to use it but it is not working in my case, Code used :

```
 private void setGravityAndText(TextView textView,String text){
   if(text.length()>24){
        textView.setIncludeFontPadding(true);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
   }
    else {
       textView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
       textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
   }
    textView.setText(text);

}
```

Horizontal alignment is working  successfully, but on the top anyway doesn't work? What did I do wrong?

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post the screen shot of the view. I think it is the default padding that you mentioning here...

Comment: @Triode http://clip2net.com/s/5RR0pt

Comment: @Abbath first remove the gravity from your layout file and try to set it dynamically only.

Comment: put ScreenShot for get reliable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `android:gravity` from `xml` and change `android:height="fill_parent"`,
Try like this:

for **XML:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/driver_passage_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ivanov Ivan Ivanich"
        android:padding="0"
        />
```

for **Java:**

```
private void setGravityAndText(TextView textView,String text){
   if(text.length()>24){
        textView.setIncludeFontPadding(true);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
   }
    else {
       textView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
       textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
   }
    textView.setText(text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `EDITTEXT`

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/driver_passage_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ma_list_item_height"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="start" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Some hint text"
></EditText>
```

Comment: Why an EditText when the OP wants a TextView?

Comment: I dunno but i had a problem like this to o..i replaced it with editext ..it solved my prob..so just a try .. And also @Abbath also try in relative layout ..